# the application has stopped working

Tags: android, android-studio

when i click add button instead of opening student details it says application has stopped working.
please help me. 
Thank you.

**This is my code:**

```
    package com.example.rahul.myapplication;

    import android.app.ListActivity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ListAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;

    public class MainActivity extends ListActivity  implements android.view.View.OnClickListener{

        Button btnAdd,btnGetAll;
        TextView student_Id;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (view== findViewById(R.id.btnAdd)){

                Intent intent;
                intent = new Intent(this,StudentDetail.class);
                intent.putExtra("student_Id",0);
                startActivity(intent);

            }else {

                StudentRepo repo = new StudentRepo(this);

                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> studentList =  repo.getStudentList();
                if(studentList.size()!=0) {
                    ListView lv = getListView();
                    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                            student_Id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.student_Id);
                            String studentId = student_Id.getText().toString();
                            Intent objIndent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),StudentDetail.class);
                            objIndent.putExtra("student_Id", Integer.parseInt( studentId));
                            startActivity(objIndent);
                        }
                    });
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter( MainActivity.this,studentList, R.layout.view_student_entry, new String[] { "id","name"}, new int[] {R.id.student_Id, R.id.student_name});
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(this,"No student!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
            btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);

            btnGetAll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGetAll);
            btnGetAll.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }







        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Add"
                android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@android:id/list"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_above="@+id/btnAdd" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="List All"
                android:id="@+id/btnGetAll"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnAdd" />

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/fab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

when i click add button instead of opening student details it says application has stopped working.
please help me. 
Thank you.
Logcat Shows

```
10-16 13:51:51.310 15064-15064/com.example.rahul.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-16 13:51:51.310 15064-15064/com.example.rahul.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.rahul.myapplication, PID: 15064
10-16 13:51:51.310 15064-15064/com.example.rahul.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.rahul.myapplication/com.example.rahul.myapplication.StudentDetail}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
10-16 13:51:51.310 15064-15064/com.example.rahul.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1794)
10-16 13:51:51.310 15064-15064/com.example.rahul.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1512)
10-16 13:51:51.310 15064-15064/com.example.rahul.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3917)
10-16 13:51:51.310 15064-15064/com.example.rahul.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3877)
10-16 13:51:51.310 15064-15064/com.example.rahul.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4200)
10-16 13:51:51.310 15064-15064/com.example.rahul.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4168)
10-16 13:51:51.310 15064-15064/com.example.rahul.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.rahul.myapplication.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:52)
10-16 13:51:51.310 15064-15064/com.example.rahul.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
10-16 13:51:51.310 15064-15064/com.example.rahul.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
10-16 13:51:51.310 15064-15064/com.example.rahul.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
10-16 13:51:51.310 15064-15064/com.example.rahul.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-16 13:51:51.310 15064-15064/com.example.rahul.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
10-16 13:51:51.310 15064-15064/com.example.rahul.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
10-16 13:51:51.310 15064-15064/com.example.rahul.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-16 13:51:51.310 15064-15064/com.example.rahul.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
10-16 13:51:51.310 15064-15064/com.example.rahul.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: What is your friend Mr. Debugger telling you?

Comment: oncreate() method should be first . before asking a question please follow coding steps

Comment: it doesn't matter how i write it

Comment: Can you please add the logcat report

Comment: i have added logcat report

Answer (score 0):

Change your code section from

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view== findViewById(R.id.btnAdd)){

            Intent intent;
            intent = new Intent(this,StudentDetail.class);
```

to

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.btnAdd){

            Intent intent;
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,StudentDetail.class);
```

> View is a class and you do not use == to compare two instance of the
>   class rather use equals methods.

Hence your condition goes into else section...In that it might be throwing some error as operation in else part might not be ready as per your logic. Because your add click event should only execute if part and not else as mentioned so do the change and check